# derivative of tensor

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, tensors

Hi I am trying to simplify
$$
A=\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_j u_i+\partial_i u_j\right)\left(\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}+\delta_{il}\delta_{jk}-\frac{2}{3}\delta_{ij}\delta_{kl}\right)\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_l u_k+\partial_k u_l\right)
$$
where $\delta_{ij}$ is the usual Kronecker delta tensor, $\delta_{ij}=1$ for $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise. Note, I am specifically trying to simplify it using $\partial_i u_i=0$.  How can we do this?  My answer doesn't match the correct one.
  My attempt was to first calculate
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}+\delta_{il}\delta_{jk}-\frac{2}{3}\delta_{ij}\delta_{kl}\right)\left(\partial_l u_k+\partial_k u_l\right)=\partial_j u_i+\partial_i u_j.
$$
Now we can write $A_{ij}$ as 
$$
A=\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_j u_i+\partial_i u_j\right)\cdot (\partial_j u_i+\partial_u u_j)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\partial_j u_i +\partial_i u_j\right)^2
$$
Expanding the square I obtained
$$
A=\frac{1}{2} \left(\partial_j u_i \partial_j u_i +\partial_i u_j \partial_i u_j+ 2\partial_i u_j \partial_j  u_i\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_j u_i \partial_j u_i +\partial_i u_j \partial_i u_j\right)+\partial_i u_j \partial_j  u_i
$$

The answer to this problem is supposed to be
$$
A= \left(\partial_j u_i \partial_j u_i +\partial_j u_i \partial_i u_j\right)
$$
which doesn't seem to be symmetric in $i,j$,
You can see this answer has three terms of the form $\partial_j u_i$, and only 1 term of the form $\partial_i u_j$.   How can I simplify my result to get this answer?  THanks.

Note
$$
\partial_j u_i\equiv \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}
$$

Comment: In expanding that square, there shouldn't be any second derivatives.

Comment: Are you using the Einstein summation convention? The constraint $\partial_i u_i $ ($=\nabla\cdot u$ if you are) seems to indicate it, but when you write $A_{ij}$ even though the rhs has repeated $i,j$ indices it seems you are not doing this.

Comment: @JohnMa Can you clarify?  I am not sure what you mean.  When expanding the square I explicitly obtained,
$$
\left(\partial_j u_i +\partial_i u_j\right)^2= \partial_j u_i \partial_j u_i +\partial_i u_j \partial_i u_j+\partial_j u_i \partial_i u_j +\partial_i u_j \partial_j u_i
$$
Is this wrong?  There are no second derivatives.  Thanks for the  help.

Comment: @Winther Yes I am, thanks for pointing out that problem.  The constraint is exactly, $\nabla\cdot u=0$.  I am not so familiar with working with this notation and differentiating tensors and such.  Do you see where I am going wrong in this problem?  Thanks.

Comment: You should remove $ij$ in  $A_{ij}$. This is a scalar quantity, not a tensor then. One error is in what John pointed out above: in your 'Expand the square' you have said $=0$ on a term that is not zero (and you have a typo with in this term so that it looks like a second derivative). For your confusion about symmetric in $ij$: note that $\partial_i u_j\partial_i u_j = \partial_j u_i\partial_j u_i$ when summation is implied.

Comment: @Winther Yes I fixed $A_{ij}$ and made it A.  THanks.  Why is $\partial_j u_j\neq 0$?  By second derivative, I assume this means $\partial_i \partial_i$, but I do not see where i have that in the squared expression.  How do you correctly square the expression?

Comment: The term you have put to zero is really $2\partial_i u_j\partial_j u_i \not= 0$.

Comment: @Winther Yes that is true, however, I thought $\partial_i u_j \partial_j u_i=u_j \partial_j \partial_i u_i$ by swapping the order of the derivatives.  That was my problem.  Thanks.  How can I then simplify that square to obtain the correct expression?

Comment: You cannot swapping the derivative (unless you are using integration by part, but in that case you have an integral $\int$) .

Comment: @JohnMa Thanks for teaching me that.  I didn't know.  I updated my answer now, I am just stuck on simplifying it to obtain the 'correct' result.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Winther I updated my post.  Thanks.

Comment: @Winther Thanks for explaining all of that.  I understand everything now.

Comment: @JohnMa Thanks for your help, I understand everything now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have figured it all out so here is just a quick answer to your final question.

The particular names we use for the summation variable(s) are just labels so we are free to change $(i,j)\to(j,i)$. Performing such a change gives us that
$$\partial_i u_j\partial_i u_j = \partial_j u_i\partial_j u_i$$

which is what you need to get to the final answer. This trick off relabeling the summation variables is a key ingedient to solving many tensor calculus problems so it's a good idea to try to remember it.